# I want to change the layout of the forum

Tags: views, panels, theming

I would like to redesign how the layout of the forum threads; very specifically, this is for a B/S/T website I am working on.

I have included a drawing of how I would eventually like them to appear. I am working with panels and views, which should be fine for putting together a page to draw it all out, but how will I be able to set these pages as the default routine to display forum threads?

[image: screenshot]

**Update:** I am starting to get somewhere. Using "Panels > Node Template," I was able to modify the forum topic template, which allowed me to at least predicate my forum topics with a view at the top of the page. I setup this view to pull pictures from the forum topic being observed by the user.
I then modified "Content Types > Forum Topic > Manage Display," where I then changed the Picture field to "HIDDEN" in terms of display. This cleans up clunky, large pictures being shown, and in the View at the top, I have setup Colorbox to display the pictures.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: OK, i am starting to get somewhere.  using Panels --> Node Template, I was able to modify the Forum Topic template, which allowed me to at least predicate my forum topics with a View at the top of the page.

Comment: no line breaks in replies, here?

Comment: I setup this view to pull pictures from the forum topic being observed by the user.

Comment: I then modified Content Types --> Forum Topic --> Manage Display, where I then changed the Picture field to HIDDEN in terms of display.


This cleans up clunky, large pictures  being shown, and in the View at the top, I have setup Colorbox to display the pictures.


DEMO: 
http://120178.tk/phswap/node/2

Comment: Looks like you are well on your way as I almost thought this was spam for a used laptop site :-)

Comment: :)

definitely not trying to spam anything.  this is a demo site i am cranking out.  recently i am now working on adding images to the forum containers, but having some trouble getting them to tabulate properly, now.  when i enclose the related data (php) in a table, it alters the span width, setting it to "auto" (by the looks of it) rather than allowing it to spread 100%..

i appreciate you checking out my work!  if anyoen wants to offer advice i will appreciate it.  feel free to keep checking the demo to see how my work is coming along if anyone is curious.  *not spam*

Comment: showing container with picture, thick border of table is intentional while troubleshooting: http://120178.tk/phswap/forum

Comment: well, it's been a few days since i messed with this, and I am finding now that my VIEW displays all images for all forum topics, no matter what.

how can i FILTER the view so it only shows images for the particular forum topic being read by the user?